# Syntax Check Library

Tags: java

I am looking to make a kind of IDE in Java . I would like to ask if there are any syntax check libraries for java (it wouldn't be bad if they support more languages).After some searching on google i got some results for javascript but not java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java (6 at least) has a [JavaCompiler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) interface.  That may be what you want.